# Use Corda `vaultQueryBy` stateRef's `txhash` to return all states for the transaction

Tags: corda

I'm using braid to query a corda node via `vaultQueryBy`. I'd like to return *all* states for a specific `txhash`, but omitting the stateRef's `index` in the query criteria causes it default the index value to `0`.

Is there any way to return all transaction states for a specific transaction hash using `vaultQueryBy`?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `vaultQueryBy`, you can use the following:

```
SignedTransaction tx = getServiceHub().getValidatedTransactions().getTransaction(tx-hash);
List<StateAndRef<your-state-type> outputs = tx.getCoreTransaction().outRefsOfType(your-state-type);
```

Comment: This is a query issue from an electron application. We are using braid to get around building our own proxy connection to the node. Braid doesn't seem to expose the `getValidatedTransactions`.

Comment: Braid server exposes your flows and services.

Comment: If you are using an in-memory braid server, then you can follow the approach of `pigtail` project from the samples repo (https://github.com/corda/samples/tree/release-V4/pigtail).

Comment: Inside `BraidService.kt` (https://github.com/corda/samples/blob/release-V4/pigtail/cordapp/src/main/kotlin/com/template/BraidService.kt), you can add this code:

Comment: Sorry comments don't allow proper formatting: fun getAllStatesAndRefsByTxHash(txHash: SecureHash): List<StateAndRef<YourState>> {
        val tx = serviceHub.validatedTransactions.getTransaction(txHash)
        return tx?.coreTransaction?.outRefsOfType(YourState::class.java)
    }

Comment: If you are using a standalone Braid server, then you can also write a flow or a class annotated with @CordaService and add the above function to them.

Comment: Have a look at my article about Braid server (in-memory and standalone): https://blog.b9lab.com/cordacon-2019-highlights-braid-server-and-openapi-generator-for-corda-flows-api-s-d24179ccb27c

Comment: The flows and services are from arbitrary cordapps the front end (Election) doesn't have operational knowledge of. I guess may need to write our own cordapp to expose these methods (I was hoping to avoid adding another build process to our workflow). It's unfortunate corda's RPC interface doesn't facilitate easy access to more core functionality (like ServiceHub) from non-java integrations. For now I'm just going to query the postgres database for the node directly.

Comment: Some background: I'm building Corda integration into Truffle's Ganache UI desktop application: https://www.r3.com/videos/truffle-and-corda/

Comment: I recommend that you contact `Farzad Pezeshkpour`, he's one of Braid developers and he's very helpful. You can find him on the Corda public slack channel (`slack.corda.net`) under the username `Fuzz`.

Comment: Thanks Adel, I did email him yesterday.